# Akka parent not receiving message from child

Tags: scala, akka

Below akka hierarchy is a parent child where the parent sends a message to the child and the child responds with value 1. But the parent does not appear to receive the value as the message "received is 1" is not printed to console.

Is my hierarchy setup correctly ? :

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props

class ChildActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case receivedValue: Int => {
      println(receivedValue);
      context.parent ! 1
    }
  }
}

object ParentChild extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem()

  val parentActor = system.actorOf(Props[ParentActor])

  class ParentActor extends Actor {

    val childActor = system.actorOf(Props[ChildActor])
    childActor ! 1
    def receive = {
      case v: Int => println("received is " + v);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Where are you sending a message to Child actor?

Comment: The problem is child actor is not actually child of parent, an actor doesn't become a child actor just be creating a reference in parent, you actually need to create a reference within the context of parent. So instead of `system.actorOf(Props[ChildActor])` you need to do `context.actorOf(Props[ChildActor])` .

Comment: @curious that works, if put into answer ill accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you created the childActor using

`val childActor = system.actorOf(Props[ChildActor])`

Which means it is a top-level actor, it's parent is ActorSystem instead of the ParentActor which you would expect

To have it work as expect, you need to create ChildActor as follow

`val childActor = context.actorOf(Props[ChildActor])`

inside `ParentActor`